# I can't add buttons in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I want to add buttons in Actionbar of Android Support library.
Actionbar is shown, but no button appears.

Below is res/menu/main.xml

```
menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

and I add following code.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

What should I do??

Comment: Is this inside an activity, or a fragment? For the later, you need to call setHasOptionsMenu(true) to have it work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: yup, he needs to inflate the menu xml

Answer (score 0):

Inside a Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Also, remember to set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your `onActivityCreated` method.

In an Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but eclipse says "onCreateOptionsMenu must override or implement a supertype method".